# Encoding issue when changing vimrc file default location

Tags: vim, encoding

I'm using Vim on Windows, and in order to "change" the `vimrc` file location I have just the following line in the `_vimrc` file that is in my home directory:

```
source $HOME\.vim\.vimrc
```

I thought everything worked just fine that way but when I tried changing the symbol for a plugin (tagbar) to a certain fancy one like this:

```
let g:tagbar_iconchars = ['▸', '▾']
```

the plugin symbol didn't show the glyph but a `<br>` character instead. I noticed that the same problem appeared when attempting to change the symbol in several other plugins (vimfiler, airline, etc) and found out that if I changed those symbols in the `_vimrc` file rather than in the new `.vimrc` file the issue was fixed.

Is there some encoding being set with the `source` command in the `_vimrc` file that is triggering my problem? I thought that "changing" the `vimrc` file location the way I did was fine, are there other problems with that method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pre-7.4 Vim, the cleanest way to source your "real" `vimrc` from the default user-level `vimrc` (`$HOME/_vimrc` (windows) or `$HOME/.vimrc` (unix)) was to place it in `$HOME/vimfiles/` (windows) or `$HOME/.vim/` (unix) and use this line line in the default user-level `vimrc`:

```
runtime vimrc
```

Since 7.4, Vim automatically tries to source `$HOME/.vimrc` *and* `$HOME/.vim/vimrc` so, if you only work with machines running 7.4, you can safely stop doing what you are trying to do.

Also, on Windows, the canonical location for your config is `$HOME/vimfiles`, not `$HOME/.vim`.

Comment: I'm using 7.4 in my machines, however I tried deleting `$HOME/_vimrc` but `$HOME/.vim/vimrc` was not automatically sourced. Regarding your last comment I've changed in Windows the runtimepath like this `set runtimepath=$HOME/.vim,$VIMRUNTIME,$HOME/.vim/after`.

Comment: Why do you use `$HOME/.vim` instead of the normal `$HOME/vimfiles`? Too simple? Just set things up normally.

Comment: I prefer it that way so it is the same across all platforms. So the automatic sourcing of `$HOME/.vim/vimrc` in 7.4 is not working as expected? I guess it doesn't work because it looks for `vimfiles` rather than `.vim`.

Comment: Yes, use `$HOME/vimfiles`, you may not like it but it is guaranteed to work without toying with `'runtimepath'`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use any special characters in a Vim script, it is recommended to put the `:scriptencoding` command at (or near) the top of the file, e.g.

```
:scriptencoding utf-8
```